# Cropped shape and created new face, how to match old subdivision

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am new to blender and it is going well, however I have a question regarding deleting parts of objects and previous subdivide.

I am creating fence line, I created the first post and then to make things easier duplicated that. To add variation I chopped the top of the post away and added a new face to cap it off, then after re-shaping it I have added a texture.

Now the problem is that the division doesn't match and it throws off the texture. How can I get the new face to match the rest of the subdivide? I have tried clicking on the face and doing a new subdivide but that doesn't seem to work.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hello :). When you edit the geometry, you need to UV unwrap the object again.

Comment: Ok thanks I i will give it ago again